# Retreive basic auth credentials from Apache server, to embed in Angular SPA?

Tags: angular, authentication, basic-authentication, jira-rest-api

My Angular SPA app is served by an Apache server that requires Basic Auth.
The app also needs to consume a REST API that requires Basic Auth (same credentials)

So when the user first navigates to the page, he must provide his credentials before the server will even send the Angular app.  However once the user gets the app, the app doesn't know what credentials to use to access the REST API.  I'd have to present the user with a second login page, so the app can store the auth credentials in a cookie or localStorage.

Is there any way I can have the server "embed" the user's $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] and $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PASSWORD'] with the Angular SPA, so the user doesn't have to login twice?

For example something like:

- user navigates to index.php wrapper
- PHP wrapper is exactly like index.html except it also stores PHP_AUTH credentials to localStorage

```html
<body>
    <script>
        localStorage.setItem("auth_token", "<?php base64_encode($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'].":".$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PASSWORD']); ?>");
    </script>
  <app-root></app-root>
...
</body>
```

- Angular gets credentials from localStorage for header to REST API

```html
getProject(): Promise<Project> {
        let auth_token = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + auth_token);
        let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
        return this.http
            .get(this.restApiUrl, options )
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json().data as Project)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

(This solution didn't work.  I get 401 Authorization Required even when I enter my credentials.)

Answer (score 0):

base64_encode returns a string or false. It doesn't print the output. For that you could use `echo`. You can verify this by looking at the source of the rendered page in your script tag. `localStorage.setItem("//php didn't output anything here")`

```
echo base64_encode($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'].":".$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PASSWORD']);
```